# Six UIViews into swipeable cube in IOS 7

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, uiimageview, xcode6

I am working on a project where I need a cube of UIViews or UIImageviews to be presented in the middle of a ViewController. Basically I want to be able to swipe up, down or sideways to rotate the cube.

My problem - creating the cube itself. What is the easiest approach to make this seemingly simple cube? I have looked at countless examples of similar projects but all of them either seem too complex or are performing the animation between view controllers. What is the easiest way to do this and are there any good examples or tutorials that I may have missed?

Comment: some background here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572493/drawing-a-3d-cube-and-rotating-it

Comment: Depending on how you want the effect to look like, you might be able to use simple transformations on your views. Still not an easy task, though.

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://github.com/ghinzuios/CubePageView

Comment: CubePageView is the one I liked the most, still I am not sure I understand it enough to modify the code to allow for the up and down swiping.